# vscode is not giving me any errors but my webpage shows up as blank upon running

Tags: html, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, redux

I'm working on a youtube tutorial that creates a social media website, and I've run into an issue with my front end code. every time I npm start, my webpage display. https://github.com/levistark1/socialsite-frontend this is my code for the front end.

[image]

^These are the errors I'm getting in console when I inspect element

[image]
This image is what my webpages shows, but it is supposed to show content on the homepage

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0&list=PLkAjsIAdaOruUp-gCIRkeJXzTRNwW2lG6&index=9

I have found multiple articles of people asking similar questions but none seem to help my case.

I found one issue with the <AuthRoute> react component, where if I remove it it shows my navbar but nothing else.

Comment: "No routes matched location /" - you would need to show your router-related code at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code of your App.js file. it seems like there's an error with the react-router-dom module usage

Comment: Please add your answer in the comment part.